# how to send image data through ajax as a parameter to spring controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

here's my jquery code:

```
var x = $('div.FileUpload img').prop('src');
var imgData = JSON.stringify(x);

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
datatype: 'json',
data: imgData,
url: "/Archives/SaveImage.html",
success: function(data) {
alert("successfully uploaded");
},
error: function (request, status, error) {
alert("failure");
}
});
```

and here's the spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Archives/SaveImage", RequestMethod.POST)
 public void SaveImage(@RequestParam(value = "imgData")Object imgData)
 { 
     System.out.println(imgData);
 }
```

the imgData is not a picture path, it's encoded bytes like below:

```
 src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgIC‌​AwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFBwYHBwcGBwcICQsJCAgKCAcHCg0KCgsMDAwMBwkODw0MDgsMDAz/2wBDAQICAgMDA‌​wYDAwYMCAcIDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAw..."
```

the problem is that in debug mode, it doesn't come to spring controller function,  and the error message is : "the requested parameter ("imgData") is not avaialable

I think it's because of the @RequestParam variable type.

can any body help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't send a parameter. You only send data. And the data you are sending is a String. If you want it to converted automatically to something else you need an appropriate converter. Anyway, what your are looking for is the `@RequestBody` annotation.

```
public void SaveImage(@RequestBody String imgData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
var imgData = JSON.stringify({'imgData': x});
```

When you send data using `data: imgData` in the AJAX, it's not sending the data with that variable name.  That's just a placeholder.  And when you used `JSON.stringify(x)` it only put the value of `x` into an object of one unnamed property (might as well have been an array).

```
JSON.stringify(x)  // "http://image.com/path.jpg"

JSON.stringify({'imgSrc': x})   //  "imgSrc": "http://image.com/path.jpg"
```

### [View demonstration here](http://jsfiddle.net/WTvxn/)

*The first image + text is your original code and the one below is the correction*

Comment: thanks for the reply, I did this, but I still have the same problem, and by the way, the imgData is not a picture path, it's encoded bytes like below:

src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFBwYHBwcGBwcICQsJCAgKCAcHCg0KCgsMDAwMBwkODw0MDgsMDAz/2wBDAQICAgMDAwYDAwYMCAcIDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAw..."
.
.
should I change the type of the sent parameter in the controller side (@RequestParam(value = "imgData")Object imgData)